# Is there any Android handler that allows to know if a tablet or mobile phone has been disconnected from electrical current?

Tags: android

Is there a way of detecting if an Android device is currently connected to a charger (either mains or USB), and are there events I can use to monitor when the device is connected or disconnected?

Comment: look at `http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html`

Answer (score 1):

Is this something that might help you?

http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html

Answer (score 1):

```
public static boolean isConnected(Context context) {
    Intent intent = context.registerReceiver(null, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
    int plugged = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1);
    return plugged == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC || plugged == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB;
}
```